# Mongoid embed_one and has_one

Tags: mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

Recently working on Mongoid, I'm confused that is embed_one in Mongoid the same as has_one? If no, what's the difference and any examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, read [mongoid documentation about relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_one)!

Mongoid Embedded 1-1

> One to one relationships where the children are embedded in the
>   parent document are defined using Mongoid's embeds_one and embedded_in
>   macros.

Mongoid Refrence 1-1

> One to one relationships where the children are referenced in the
>   parent document are defined using Mongoid's has_one and belongs_to
>   macros.

From [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-embedding) :

`embeds_one` Benefits against `has_one`

> - generally better performance for read operations.
> - the ability to request and retrieve related data in a single database operation.

Large data problem :

> Embedding related data in documents, can lead to situations where
>   documents grow after creation. Document growth can impact write
>   performance and lead to data fragmentation. Furthermore, documents in
>   MongoDB must be smaller than the maximum BSON document size.

That happens when using `embeds_many`.

`embeds_one` embeds model inside another model but `has_one` save reference in model.

Mongodb save document in database this way (From [Mongodb examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-example-one-to-one))

Reference 1-1 :

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader"
}

{
   patron_id: "joe",
   street: "123 Fake Street",
   city: "Faketon",
   state: "MA"
   zip: 12345
}
```

Embedded 1-1

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   address: {
              street: "123 Fake Street",
              city: "Faketon",
              state: "MA"
              zip: 12345
            }
}
```